# is that possible that one git repo but each dir in it is distributed on different pcs?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, configuration

I know svn can handle this, for example the svn repo would have directroies such as

```
 svnrepo/trunk/
   pc1
   pc2
   ...
   pcn
```

then on user only needs to checkout `svnrepo/trunk/pc1`, and another checkouts `trunk/pcn`.

But if I use git, until now, I know all users will have all the files, for example, there will be `pc1, pc2...pcn` on while only `pc` is needed

Sometimes this could be confusing.

So is that possible to have one git repo but each dir is distributed indepdendently from the others?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, specifically, with the different directories? There are git ways to do most anything, but odds are your end result won't be nearly so complex.

Comment: The "git way" would be to have each one of those directories (are these different projects?) as different repositories. Then each person can check whichever repos she needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my honest view you're trying to use git the same way you use svn.
Using git you won't accomplish this (and even if you can using some strangely advanced commands) I would never recommend that.

What you can quite easily do is have a different .gitignore in each pc and create a process to update it without merging and resolving conflicts which would always exist. Of course this is definitely an expensive an not necessary process.

The concept in git is everybody have the whole repository. This is not a drawback. SVN probably have such mentioned capability due to the network traffic it uses and the lack of a decent merging strategy.

Whatever you are trying to do, I suggest you trying in the "git" way, which means lots of commits and lots of merges without any fear.

Comment: so the assumption of git is not always good, since sometimes only part of the code is enough

Comment: Depends on what "enough" means. But yes the assumption is everybody having the whole repository in order to work, even though you'll just work on a small piece of code.
You can use submodules in git, which are "embed" repositories. In such case there's actually a repository dependency. I consider handing submodules a small pain so I don't advice you to do that unless this is really your scenario.